# usage of refrain and abstain

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I am frequently confused regarding two words : refrain and abstain. I understand that abstain has negative connotations as it conveys that something must be stopped. On the other hand, refrain carries a positive sense. I mean I have desire, however I am compelled to stop. Am I right? For instance

*In spite of my desire, I **refrain** myself from going outdoor.*

*I promise to **abstain** from alcohol.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "refrain yourself".  Refrain is an intransitive verb. You just say, "I refrained from going outdoors".  The meaning is that you could have gone outdoors, but for some reason judged it better not to do so.

Abstain is also intransitive eg, "I abstain from junk food".  There it means something ongoing, but it also refers to one-off behaviours, like abstaining from a vote at the UN. However, they don't refrain at the UN.

A lot of refraining goes on in the bible, where contrary examples may be found, but this represents an archaic style.

It is possible that you are thinking of "restrain" which is transitive. You can restrain yourself or somebody else, or restrain an urge.

Answer (score 1):

No you are not correct and I am confused that you would think this was the case.

> **[abstain](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/abstain)** - restrain oneself from doing or enjoying something
>
> **[refrain](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/refrain)** - Stop oneself from doing something

Neither of these is good or bad, they are in fact neutral the only connotation is that what you are **abstaining** from is something enjoyable, it bears no moral judgement. And **abstain** does not mean that anything *should* be avoided.

Comment: Can we use both words in willingness and unwillingness ? I am sorry if I can't be able to explain my question. I mean stop oneself whether it is desired action, substance (because of the circumstances, unwillingly) or something that must be stopped (because it is bad). For instance, **In spite of my desire, I refrain myself from going outdoor** and **I'm going to refrain from eating junk food.** Do both sentence make sense ?

Comment: yes, they can both be used that way, they would both make sense. :)